# Function error (R) - object not found? - R programming course

Tags: r

I am currently doing an R programming course where I have to write a function to calculate the mean of a pollutant (sulfate or nitrate) across a specified list of monitors. The function 'pollutantmean' takes three arguments: 'directory', 'pollutant', and 'id'. Given a vector monitor ID numbers, 'pollutantmean' reads that monitors' particulate matter data from the directory specified in the 'directory' argument and returns the mean of the pollutant across all of the monitors, ignoring any missing values coded as NA.

The zip file containing the data:  https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/rprog%2Fdata%2Fspecdata.zip

Below is my function. When I run it I get this error which I don't understand.

error -

Error in pollutantmean("specdata", "sulfate", 1:10) : object 'df_list' not found

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id=1:332) {

filenames <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE, pattern = "csv")
idx <- 1
for (i in id)
{
    filename <- read.csv(filenames[i])
    df_list[[idx]] <- filename$pollutant
    idx <- idx + 1
}
df <- data.table::rbind(df_list)
colMeans(df, na.rm=TRUE)
```

}

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Welcome to SO! You assign values to the list `df_list` before you initialise the list. Try to write `df_list <- list()` after the `filenames <- list.files...` row.`

Comment: Hi @starja Thanks a lot for your response!! I did that and now get this error  Error: 'rbind' is not an exported object from 'namespace:data.table'  -

Comment: I tried doing it like this however when I try printing the df_list to see if its correct its empty.... maybe the way I read the files or something is incorrect?...

Comment: pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id=1:332) {
    
    filenames <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE, pattern = "csv")
    df_list <- list()
    idx <- 1
    for (i in id)
    {
        filename <- read.csv(filenames[i])
        df_list <- c(df_list, filename$pollutant)
    }
    print(df_list)
    mean(df_list, na.rm=TRUE)
}

Comment: Try `df <- do.call("rbind", df_list)`. It could be that the reading in of the files is not correct, without seeing the data it is hard to tell. If you want to learn more about debugging, have a look [here](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/debugging.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `pollutantmean()` function is supposed to return the mean of one pollutant that is specified as an argument to the function. The code posted in the question has a number of problems that prevent it from producing correct answers to the example problems:

```
pollutantmean("specdata","sulfate",1:10)
pollutantmean("specdata", "nitrate", 70:72) 
pollutantmean("specdata", "nitrate", 23)
```

First, as noted in the comments, the object `df_list` is uninitialized print to the `for()` loop. We can correct this by adding the following line of code prior to the loop.

```
df_list <- list()
```

Second, the code uses the `$` form of the extract operator to extract the pollutant from the data frames read with `read.csv()`. This fails because `$` does not work with variable substitution, as I discuss in [Forms of the Extract Operator](https://github.com/lgreski/datasciencectacontent/blob/master/markdown/rprog-extractOperator.md).  We correct this by using the `[` form of the extract operator because it has the side effect of returning a data frame instead of a vector.

```
df_list[[idx]] <- filename[pollutant]
```

After the `for()` loop completes, `df_list` is a list of data frames.

Next, we replace `data.table::rbind()` with `data.table::rbindlist()` to process the list of data frames.

At this point, `df` is a single data frame with one column, which allows `colMeans()` to return a single mean.

With these edits, the code produces correct results for the examples provided by the JHU instructors:

```
> pollutantmean("specdata","sulfate",1:10)
 sulfate 
4.064128 
> pollutantmean("specdata", "nitrate", 70:72) 
 nitrate 
1.706047 
> pollutantmean("specdata", "nitrate", 23)
 nitrate 
1.280833 
>
```

**NOTE:** since I am a Community Mentor in the JHU Data Science Specialization, I will not post a complete answer to the programming assignment because doing so violates the Coursera Honor Code.